# Why is a printers device context smaller than reported in MFC?

Tags: c++, printing, mfc, gdi

I've run into a problem when printing using MFC. The problem is I'm told the printable area is 201x288mm, but I am actually finding it to be 200.9x287.9mm.

To illustrate the issue, I created a blank TabbedDocument MFC application in Visual Studio 2008, using the wizard. In my 'view' class (CPrintingExampleView - PrintingExample being the name I gave the test project), I added the following code to the OnDraw(CDC* pDC) method:

```
pDC->SetMapMode( MM_LOMETRIC );

int width = GetDeviceCaps( pDC->m_hDC, HORZSIZE );
int height = GetDeviceCaps( pDC->m_hDC, VERTSIZE );

// TODO: add draw code for native data here
RECT rect;
int result = pDC->GetClipBox( (LPRECT)&rect );

//draw a 201x288mm square
pDC->MoveTo( 0, 0 );
pDC->LineTo( 2010, 0 );
pDC->LineTo( 2010, -2880 );
pDC->LineTo( 0, -2880 );
pDC->LineTo( 0, 0 );

BOOL visible = pDC->PtVisible( 0, 0 );
visible = pDC->PtVisible( 0, -1 );
visible = pDC->PtVisible( 1, 0 );
visible = pDC->PtVisible( 1, -1 );
visible = pDC->PtVisible( rect.right, rect.bottom );
visible = pDC->PtVisible( rect.right-1, rect.bottom+1 );
visible = pDC->PtVisible( rect.right-1, rect.bottom );
visible = pDC->PtVisible( rect.right, rect.bottom+1 );
```

Now, ignoring the hard-coded values etc - this is just an illustration of the problem - After clicking "OK" on the print dialog (when the CDC* passed to OnDraw is the printer's DC), the values of rect I get are: left = 0, top = 0, right = 2010, bottom = -2880, which tallies with the width and height variables' values which are 201 and 288 respectively.
Next I draw the 201x288mm box, this prints without the right hand and bottom line, which are clipped.
Then to confirm the problem I call PtVisible to check the various points, the only points that fail this check are:

```
    (rect.right, rect.bottom)
    (rect.right-1, rect.bottom)
    (rect.right, rect.bottom+1)
```

The code I have shown is the only edit I made to the generated program. Can anyone confirm that this is indeed a problem? If so can anyone suggest what is the correct approach to dealing with this? My gut is to just 'adjust' the information retrieved from GetDeviceCaps() and assume the width and height are 0.1mm smaller than reported, but I feel like I'm missing something?

Comment: The unprintable margins will come from the printer driver. You're at the mercy of how careful they were when coding it.

Comment: Is this not simply an off-by-one error?

Comment: Maybe your printer paper ist just not the right size?

Comment: Just a thought; the docs mention printers specifically only for the `HORZRES` GetDeviceCaps value. `HORZSIZE` only mentions screens. Might be a docs error, mind you.

Comment: Thanks for the help so far everyone :). @Rook, I switch the MapMode to MM_TEXT and used the values from HORZRES and VERTRES to create the rectangle, the same problem occurs. I don't think it's an off-by-one error, because I'm starting at 0, and if I can't use the limit, then the area is smaller than reported.

I'm inclined to believe Mark Ransom was right with it being a driver inaccuracy, but if it is, then surely it will work properly on a few printers, so far 2 of 2 have this problem, which makes me sceptical, will have to try it on a larger selection of printers...

Comment: Now it's 3 out of 3 that exhibit this behaviour.

Comment: The MSDN page on `GetDeviceCaps()` has this to say "Note  GetDeviceCaps reports info that the display driver provides. If the display driver declines to report any info, GetDeviceCaps calculates the info based on fixed calculations. If the display driver reports invalid info, GetDeviceCaps returns the invalid info. Also, if the display driver declines to report info, GetDeviceCaps might calculate incorrect info because it assumes either fixed DPI (96 DPI) or a fixed size (depending on the info that the display driver did and didn’t provide)."

Comment: May be you need some conversion from device coordinates to logical coordinates, calling the DPtoLP.

Comment: Better late than never: If you have 2010 pixels and the first one is zero, the last one is 2009, not 2010. Yes, GDI doesn't draw the last pixel of lines because of that weird pixel addressing thing it does, but when you draw a line from 2010,0 to 2010,-2880, the entire line is one pixel too far to the right and off the page.